# NTVDM CPU error

Tags: malware, ms-dos, malware-removal, ntvdm

When I try to run a Symantec fix [here](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/global/removal_tool/threat_writeups/FixDownadup.exe), I get the following error:

```
16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem
The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction.
CS:393a IP:393a OP:ff ff ff ff ff Choose 'Close' to terminate the application.
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download is corrupt.  The MS-DOS subsystem shouldn't be trying to run that file; It's a Windows executable.  For some reason it's not being detected as a valid Windows application and being run in MS-DOS mode, but it's not a DOS application so it crashes.

Just re-download the EXE or complain to Symantec